# Calculation of coefficients of a Fourier series

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, fourier-series

Calculating the Fourier series of a periodic function I need to evaluate these integrals:
$$1)  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dt\left(\cos^{-1}(\alpha t-1)+2(1-\alpha t)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\alpha t-\frac{1}{4}\alpha^2t^2}\right)\sin(t)$$
$$2)  \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dt\left(\cos^{-1}(\alpha t-1)+2(1-\alpha t)\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\alpha t-\frac{1}{4}\alpha^2t^2}\right)\cos(t)$$ Knowing alpha, it's easy to calculate $1)$ and $2)$ numerically. The problem is that I don't know $\alpha$, so I would like to have an analytical evaluation of these two integrals. Is there some method to calculate them? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not too helpful (kind of obvious), but I think the first step is to recognize that each of them is an integral of a sum, which can be simplified to a sum of integrals.

As for actually integrating the part on the right....not sure.

Comment: I tried it, but without any result

Comment: when I come across something like this I look in integral tables and/or try mathematica's symbolic integrator.

Comment: Maple didn't find it and so does Mathematica.